# Reduce power usage while computer is "off"

Tags: power-supply, power, power-management

Recently I bought a device to measure the wattage from devices. To test the apparatus I measured 6 watts from an IKEA LED light bulb which was supposed to produce 6 watt usage and a few laptop adapters. The apparatus seems to work.

Then I tested my work in progress home server. It surprised me the server demanded **25 watts** while it was turned off. So I searched some and it appeared normal for desktop machines to demand some wattage for a bunch of functions like waking up the desktop through LAN. Though 25 wattage seems an awful lot.

Then I turned off the power button on the power supply so I could no longer turn on the server. I would suspect 0 watts to be demanded, instead, a steady **13 watts** is demanded by the desktop.

I tried all sorts of BIOS shenanigans to be found on the internet to reduce wattage while the server is off. I can't seem to get below the 25 watts.

What is going on? So far the only idea as to what could be the problem is a faulty power supply which is making an internal short circuit or something.

*What can I do to make wattage usage acceptable (~5 watts) when I turn off the server?*

Some pictures as to my current setup and bios settings:

[image]

The power supply is a Cooler master RS-520-ASAA-A1.

Comment: It would be easier to use hardware that did this.  There are specific products that prevent "vampire power usage".  Outside of those products there really isn't much you can do about it.  Your hardware is working within their specifications its your expectation that are faulty.

Comment: If you detach the PSU from the computer, does it still draw 13W when off?

Comment: Yes, PSU only (without connections to the computer) still draws 13 when turned off.

Comment: Unless you’re fully equipped with ErP Lot 6 devices, you can never achieve acceptable standby power consumption. Even though the EU took away our proper vacuum cleaners, it also has its good sides. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I mailed the manufacturer and the 13W is indeed too high and unexpected. Most consumer wattage measurement devices measure Volt-amps which is different then wattage.

Turns out the PSU consumes 3.9 watts, while consuming 21 VA, explaining the difference.